# Replace variables in all php files

Tags: php, variables, replace

I have a tough question about replacing certain variable name across all php files, i.e. to rename `_$foo_` to `_$bar["foo"]_` in all the php files. I'm planning to read all the php file as text and replace the desired variables, then write back the php file as text.

But the difficult point is, i cannot just replace *$foo* with *$bar["foo"]* directly, cases are:
1) `_echo "hello $foo";_` <-- need to replace as:
`_echo "hello ".$bar["foo"];_`  or  `_echo "hello {$bar["foo"]}";_`

2) `_echo 'hello $foo';_` <-- no need to replace anything

I could imagine there will be many complex cases to handle. Wondering if there's any existing tools or libraries can do this kind of replace safely, or anyone have a better algorithm to handle? Thanks a lot.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19758/tools-for-php-code-refactoring might be of interest

Comment: actually i have a language file with tens of thousands of variables need to rename. I have the list of variable names on hand, and intended to pass the variables into the script, let it loop through the variable list and replace in all php files.

Comment: probably writing a small php script to do the replace is the only way, there are several ways i can think of after reading in each php file  
1) split the content by the variable name, then analyze each element to decide which variables in the page need to be replaced, then write back the new php  
2) grab statement by statement from the php file, and see whether the variable is inside the quotes, and decide how to rename the variable.

Comment: but both ways took a lot of programming work in checking the conditions and easy to miss some cases, so i wonder if anyone did it before or have useful tools for this task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample perl script that do the job for the examples you've given:

updated to accept many replacements.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Modern::Perl;

my %repl = ('$foo' => '{$bar["foo"]}', '$baz' => '{$bar["baz"]}');
while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    say "before : $_";
    foreach my $key(keys %repl) {
        s/(_[^']*)(\Q$key\E)([^']*_)/$1$repl{$2}$3/;
    }
    say "after  : $_";
    say '-'x80;
}

__DATA__
_$foo_
_echo "hello $foo";_
_echo "hello ".$bar["foo"];_
_echo "hello {$bar["foo"]}";_
_echo 'hello $foo';_
$foo = "abc";
_$baz_
_echo "hello $baz";_
_echo "hello ".$bar["baz"];_
_echo "hello {$bar["baz"]}";_
_echo 'hello $baz';_
$baz = "abc";
```

**output:**

```
before : _$foo_
after  : _{$bar["foo"]}_
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
before : _echo "hello $foo";_
after  : _echo "hello {$bar["foo"]}";_
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
before : _echo "hello ".$bar["foo"];_
after  : _echo "hello ".$bar["foo"];_
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
before : _echo "hello {$bar["foo"]}";_
after  : _echo "hello {$bar["foo"]}";_
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
before : _echo 'hello $foo';_
after  : _echo 'hello $foo';_
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
before : $foo = "abc";
after  : $foo = "abc";
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
before : _$baz_
after  : _{$bar["baz"]}_
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
before : _echo "hello $baz";_
after  : _echo "hello {$bar["baz"]}";_
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
before : _echo "hello ".$bar["baz"];_
after  : _echo "hello ".$bar["baz"];_
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
before : _echo "hello {$bar["baz"]}";_
after  : _echo "hello {$bar["baz"]}";_
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
before : _echo 'hello $baz';_
after  : _echo 'hello $baz';_
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
before : $baz = "abc";
after  : $baz = "abc";
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with php as follows:

```
file_put_contents("filename", preg_replace("#{?\$foo}?#", "{\$bar['foo']}", file_get_contents("filename")));
```

If it is one-time just use a decent text-editor, e.g. [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/).

[edit]After your comment:[/edit]

```
$orFile = file_get_contents("filename");
$newFile = preg_replace("#^(\s*)\$foo#U","\\1$bar['foo']",$orFile);
$newFile = preg_replace("#{?\$foo}?#", "{\$bar['foo']}");
```

Comment: i can write a small script to loop through all the files and loop through all the variable names that I have on hand, but your's script will wrongly replace e.g. $foo = "abc";  =>  {$bar['foo']} = "abc"; Is it?

Comment: Well you can check if there is only whitespace before, that should clear 99% of all instances.

Answer (score 1):

What i usually do, and has saved me a lot of time, is use the     `replace in files` built it in my editor. Easy and fast.

[image]

Comment: thx for your suggestion, but my case is more complex then just simply replacing text with other text

Comment: and most importantly there are 10000+ variables, and 100+ php files need to process orz...

Comment: the editor will not take as nearly as much time to do the 100+ files than to set this the right way in php, plus text editors usually have regEx feature which as far as you can get with string manipulation in php.. my Editor is jEdit btw..

Answer (score 0):

Either write a script in PHP or use advanced SED if you are on linux environment.

http://lowfatlinux.com/linux-sed.html

However I would recommend you write a script, as you might be having different types of cases, and this is a program code, not a news article, so no scope of syntax error.

Comment: yah, writing a program code is what i think, but it's prone to error as there are many cases to handle, and the checking will be very complicated, just to see any existing tools can be used or other ideas